# two method using appendChild, but the result is different

Tags: javascript, appendchild

Help! I use two methods to add child nodes inside the node. But the results are different! Two kinds of code are below.
[image][image][image][image]

first code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
        <ul id="ulid">
            <li>第一个</li>
            <li>第二个</li>
            <li>第三个</li>
        </ul>
        <br/>
        <input type="button" value="添加" onclick="add1();"/>
    </body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
       function add1(){
           var li1 = document.createElement("li")
           var text1 = document.createTextNode("下一个")
           li1.appendChild(text1)
           document.getElementById("ulid").appendChild(li1);
        }
    </script>
</html>
```

second code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
        <ul id="ulid">
            <li>第一个</li>
            <li>第二个</li>
            <li>第三个</li>
        </ul>
        <br/>
        <input type="button" value="添加" onclick="add1();"/>
    </body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
       function add1(){
           var li1 = document.createElement("li").appendChild(document.createTextNode("下一个"))
           document.getElementById("ulid").appendChild(li1);
        }
    </script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The method `appendChild` returns the node that was appended, in this case it is the text node.
Then you append the text node to the `ul`, which removes it from being a child of the `li` to be a child of the `ul`.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild#Returns

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild#Returns